# How loop through child node in XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have a JSON object returned from a `HTTP` request and I've converted this into XML however the object that's being returned become an `array` objects. Now I am using XSL to render out the returned converted objects.

This is the kind of object I'm getting back after converting JSON to XML

```
<Results>
<0>
    <Codes>5051946526135</Codes>
    <Images>http://www.cheaney.co.uk/images/cheaney-arthur-iii-brogue-in-original-chestnut-calf-leather-p6-1109_image.jpg</Images>
</0>
<1>
    <Codes>5051946523974</Codes>
    <Images>http://www.bagsbydiamonds.co.uk/ekmps/shops/bagsbydiamonds/images/radley-al…-black-leather-shoulder-bag-workbag-3-compartments-rrp-199-[2]-11903-p.jpg</Images>
</1>
</Results>
```

I've been trying to use `<xsl:for-each>` however the objects are not being shown in my HTML, so I'm assuming that there's something wrong with my XSL template.

```
<xsl:template match="/Results">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Images"/> 
      </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <p> <xsl:apply-templates select="Codes"/> </p> 
  </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I thought using `*` or `.` would selected all child nodes but clearly it didn't work for me. It would have been easier if the child nodes are the same like `<collection></collection>` rather than `0 and 1`.

How can I loop through these kind of collections?

Comment: your select should match the XML, `Image` will not match `Images` as well as `Code` for `Codes`

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo, but its still not showing anything.

Comment: Elements must begin in a letter, so your input XML is invalid.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Yeah looks like it, is there a way to convert array numbers `0` to letters or more meaningful.

Comment: @nCore You need to fix this at the JSON conversion process step (of which we know nothing). XSLT can only process XML, which your current input is not.

Comment: I'm using a third party to do the JSON conversion, using https://github.com/abdmob/x2js not sure if they support converting array to letter